# Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We are using mysql 5.7.22 on centos and I have created user with this command:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE
TEMPORARY TABLES , CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ,SHOW VIEW,EVENT ON
`s_ws`.* TO test@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Test@123';

GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO test@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now I want to create SP through above user with this definer (we cant remove definer clause `s_sp`@`localhost`):

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `s_ws`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `aaa`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`s_sp`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `aaa`()
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER BEGIN  SELECT 'hello-world';

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Super is global privileges. You also need the EXECUTE on the s_ws schema:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `s_ws`.* TO test@'%' 
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO test@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I know after super privileges it will fix but super privilege would also give some exceptional privileges as well. Is there any other work around